# Points in fifth middle Cantor set sends to points in fifth middle Cantor set. by a function.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, cantor-set

Let $$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1-x &   if  & x \in [0,1]- \{\frac{1}{10}, \frac{1}{2}\}  \\
             \\ \frac{1}{2} &  if & x=\frac{1}{10} \\
             \\ \frac{1}{10} &  if  & x= \frac{1}{2}
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

Let $C_5$ the fifth middle Cantor set and $C^{\circ}=\{x \in C_{5}: x \text{ is not an end point of a contiguous interval of } C_{5}\}.$ Prove $f(C_5)=C_5$ and $f(C^{\circ})=C^{\circ}$.

Just what I have is that $|x-\frac{1}{2}|= |f(x)-\frac{1}{2}|$, for all $x \in [0,1]- \{\frac{1}{10}, \frac{1}{2}\}$. But I don't know if its enough to prove it. Could you help me?

Comment: If $f(x)$ were just $1-x$, and there was not this business about $\frac12$ and $\frac{1}{10}$, could you write a similar (true) statement? What would it be?

Comment: the same way, $f(x)=1-x$ and $|x-\frac{1}{2}|=|f(x)-\frac{1}{2}|$, but what could I do after that?

Comment: Two famous problem-solving strategies: (1) Solve a simpler problem. (2) Draw a picture. ([& there are others...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It)) What happens if you use $C_1$ or $C_2$ instead of $C_5$?